# Why do I get no error when running the same Python script on multiple terminals at the same time?

Tags: linux, file, file-pointer

I know from experience that if I try to open the same file in Vim in multiple terminals at the same time, I get an error. (Maybe because of temporary files?)

And I know from experience that if I open a text file in Python and read through it, I have to reset the pointer when I'm done.

But I've found that if I run the same Python script in multiple terminals at the same time, I don't get any error; it just successfully runs the script in both. How does this work? Doesn't Python need to read my script from the beginning in order to run it? Is the script copied to a temporary file, or something?

Answer (score 0):

> I know from experience that if I try to open the same file in Vim in multiple terminals at the same time, I get an error.

That's not actually true. Vim actually *will* let you open the same file in multiple terminals at the same time; it's just that it gives you a warning first to let you know that this is happening, so you can abort before you make changes. (It's not safe to modify the file concurrently in two different instances of Vim, because the two instances won't coordinate at all.)

Furthermore, Vim will only give you this warning if you try to open the same file *for editing* in multiple terminals at the same time. It won't complain if you're just opening the file for *reading* (using the `-R` flag).

> And I know from experience that if I open a text file in Python and read through it, I have to reset the pointer when I'm done.

That's not exactly true, either. If you make multiple separate calls to `open`, you'll have multiple separate file objects, and each separately maintains its position in the file. So something like

```py
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as first:
    with open('filename.txt', 'r') as second:
        print(first.read())
        print(second.read())
```

will print the complete contents of filename.txt *twice*.

The only reason you'd need to reset the position when you're done reading a file is if you want to use the same file object to read the file again, or if you've opened the file in read/write mode (`r+` rather than `r`) and you now want to switch from reading to writing.

> But I've found that if I run the same Python script in multiple terminals at the same time, I don't get any error; it just successfully runs the script in both. How does this work? Doesn't Python need to read my script from the beginning in order to run it? Is the script copied to a temporary file, or something?

As I think should now be clear — there's no problem here. There's no reason that two instances of Python *can't* both read the same script file at the same time. Linux allows that. (And in fact, if you delete the file, Linux will keep the file on disk until all programs that had it open have either closed it or exited.)

In fact, there's also no reason that two processes can't *write* to the same file at the same time, though here you have to be very careful to avoid the processes causing problems for each other or corrupting the file.

Answer (score -1):

terminal is just running the command you said it to execute, there is no pointer or anything
you jus